# Regex , replacing in string only chars which are outside quotation marks ("")

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

It is too difficult for me to find a proper pattern which will replace only chars which are outside quotation marks inside the string itself ,

Example :

```
string Code = "string a = \"David\";";
```

or :

```
string CodeLine = "if(Code==\"*This+is-string*\"){int a=b*c;}";
```

After the replace the output should be like this :

```
"if( Code == \"*This+is-string*\" )\n{\nint a = b * c;\n}"
```

But the problem is that my regex is replacing and ordering chars inside the quotation marks and then the output looks like this :

```
"if( Code == \" * This + is - string * \" )\n{\nint a = b * c;\n}"
```

As you see it arranging inside the "string" that is inside the CodeLine string ...

I am working on a smart indenting for a code editor . 
So now i am trying to make a arranger which will make the code look better (like in VS it automatically inserts spaces and new lines after ending block or line ";" .

Here is my regex :

```
public string Arrange_String( string String )
    {

        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\w)([\]\[!#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-])" , @"$1 $2"  );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"([\]\[!#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-])(\w)" , @"$1 $2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\s*)(\.)" , @"$2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\.)(\s*)" , @"$1" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\s*)(\()" , @"$2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\))(\s*)" , @"$1" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\s*)(\[)" , @"$2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\])(\s*)(\W)" , @"$1$3" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\s*)" + @"(""""|@""""|''|@"".*?""|(?<!@)(?<range>"".*?[^\\]"")|'.*?[^\\]')" + @"(\s*)" , @" $2 " );
        return String;
    }
```

Edit :

After one hour i found one effective and easy solution for that .
firstly here is my code :

```
public string Arrange_Code( string Main_String )
    {
        string Final_String = "";
        string Accumulated_String = "";
        bool Accumulate = true;
        bool Igonre = false;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < Main_String.Length ; i++ )
        {
            if ( Main_String[i] == '\"' )
            {
                Igonre = false;
                if ( i > 1 )
                {
                    if ( Main_String[i - 1] == '\\' || Main_String[i - 1] == '\"' )
                    {
                        Igonre = true;
                    }
                }
                if ( Igonre == false )
                {
                    if ( Accumulate == true )
                    {
                        Accumulate = false;
                        if ( Accumulated_String.Length != 0 )
                        {
                            Final_String += Arrange_String( Accumulated_String );
                        }
                        Accumulated_String = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Accumulate = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ( Accumulate == true )
            {
                Accumulated_String += Main_String[i];
            }
            else
            {
                Final_String += Main_String[i];
            }
        }
        return Final_String + Accumulated_String;
    }

    public string Arrange_String( string String )
    {
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\w)([\]\[!#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-])" , @"$1 $2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"([\]\[!#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-])(\w)" , @"$1 $2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\s*)(\.)" , @"$2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\.)(\s*)" , @"$1" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\s*)(\()" , @"$2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\))(\s*)" , @"$1" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\s*)(\[)" , @"$2" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\])(\s*)(\W)" , @"$1$3" );
        String = Regex.Replace( String , @"(\s*)" + @"(""""|@""""|''|@"".*?""|(?<!@)(?<range>"".*?[^\\]"")|'.*?[^\\]')" + @"(\s*)" , @" $2 " );
        return String;
    }
```

Before using the Regex replace , i am trying to find the parts of the string which really needs the replace with the "Arrange_Code" method .

Comment: I go "uhg" when I see questions deal with regular expressions and balanced quotes (not to mention escape handling if done right); it's even more "uhg" when trying to deal with the inverse in one go. At the *very least* a lexer/tokenizer should be used.

Comment: Please don't use `String` as a variable name.

Comment: (A lexer would yield the stream: [`if`, `(`, `Code,` `==`, `"*This+is-string*"`, `)`, `{`, `int`, etc] which can be much more cleanly dealt with. The next step would be a parser, but a lexer alone will easily allow enough extraction/analysis for basic formatting.)

Comment: How can that ever compile??? OMG now I understand what the Mayas have been warning us about...

Comment: "Please don't use String as a variable name"

It does not matter if i will use the "String" as a variable name at all , It hides the String class anyway . But you right , Better to give it else name which is not used by another class .

"How can that ever compile???"
If you are talking about the code itself , You can compile a string to Executable via MSBuild or CodeDom .
If you are talking about the Regex , It actually works anyway . But not exactly the way i want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search you are trying to compile is not regular thus regular expression should not be applied. Write a parser for stuff like this.

The problem is that the quotation mark serves as an opening tag, a closing tag and as a character depending on its context. And it is used in context with an escape character which itself can be escaped. Basically it is very much like parsing XML with regex - just don't do it!

Comment: I think that the issue is already solved . I used my solution for it and it gave me the best results i wanted .